# Can't install Ubuntu, log goes crazy, pops the low disk space error, installation crashes

Tags: dual-boot, live-usb, crash, disk-usage, log

So I built a new computer on which I was planning on having Windows and Linux (Ubuntu or Mint). Specs: i5 8400, 16GB RAM, 250GB SSD, GTX 960, connected via Ethernet, also has a WiFi card.

I have 5 personal computers running windows/linux, a linux server, a pfsense router and a security camera system of raspberry pis. I mention this as to make known that this is not my first experience building a computer and installing Linux on the side of windows.

The SSD was partitioned in half, Windows was installed first, and then it was time for Linux to install into the uncallocated half. (Windows was, and still is running perfectly fine.)

I created a bootable 8gb usb with Mint, entered Mint, and started the isntallation process. After about 5min, a message telling me "Low Disk Space" appeared and the isntallation crashed.

I now created a bootable 32gb usb with Ubuntu. Same.

I manually created the root, a swap and home. Same.

I did not understand how the computer was running out of memory, it had plenty of RAM, and plenty of SSD space. Then, by troubleshooting, I noticed that when Linux live started, a was a core was on 100%, the RAM was slowly losing space, and the thumb drive was also losing space.

So what is being created in the live drive that is choking the computer?

Well, the problem is on the /var/log folder.

Specifically, kern.log and syslog, the same log is printed over and over at impressive speeds:

```
May 10 19:02:14 ubuntu kernel: [   20.795889] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1c.0
May 10 19:02:14 ubuntu kernel: [   20.795895] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
May 10 19:02:14 ubuntu kernel: [   20.795896] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0:   device [8086:a33c] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
May 10 19:02:14 ubuntu kernel: [   20.795897] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0:    [ 0] RxErr
```

I searched for these errors, but there was really no solution or full understanding of the problem I could find. Found suggestions of changing the chipset, but, is that really where Linux is today? I am extremely burned out, as troubleshooting prevented me from getting to bed at a reasonable time. If anybody has a solution or recommendation, it is very welcomed. Until then, windows will have to do.

Comment: Looks like you have some kind of hardware fault on your PCIe bus. Ubuntu is not designed to work on faulty hardware.

Answer (score 0):

A [LiveUSB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Live_USB) works entirely in your computer's PC, writing nothing to disk, until you tell it to install something. An initial ramdisk loads a temporary root file system into memory then the Linux startup begins. That's what's taking up your memory, and once the installation completes and the PC reboots, the memory consumption goes away.

FYI, all LiveUSB filesystem writes to a [casper filesystem overlay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casper_(persistency)) (casper-rw) which writes back to the USB flashdrive.